# android java solve equations in string format

Tags: java, android, equation

I need to solve string equations in an android app, e.g. "3 + 4*(5 - log(100))". I have tried to use BeanShell for this, unfortunately I have some problems with the integer/decimal numbers. When I enter

```
 Interpreter interpreter = new Interpreter();
 String res = "9223372036854775807D";
 interpreter.eval("result = " + res);
 res = interpreter.get("result").toString();
 res = new BigDecimal(res).stripTrailingZeros().toPlainString();
```

I get as result `9223372036854776000`??

But when I use `String res = "9223372036854775807D";` I get the correct `9223372036854775807`.
I simply cannot suspitude all `D` to `L` because then I get wrong results when having somthing like `3L/2L -> 1 (but should be 1.5` 
Does anyone know how to handle huge numbers such as `9223372036854775807 or -9223372036854775808` or can anyone suggest an alternative to BeanShell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use MathEval download it from this link: http://tech.dolhub.com/code/matheval

Answer (score 1):

have you tried [JEP](http://www.singularsys.com/) expression parser?
it is a Good mathematical expression parser purely written in Java and can parse trigonometric,logarithm functions, complex values and you can customize your own functions also...